# C++ ifstream error: can't read data

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read a dataset file(space delimited numbers such as 0.5678) with fstream, but it can't read the dataset and return the same strange value for all data entries

```
ifstream input_file('Data_file');

for (int j = 1; j <= dimension; j++){
    for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_data_points; i++){
        double x;
        input_file >> x;
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

The above code returns ,

```
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
-9.25596e+61
.........
```

I have no idea how to debug it. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also *show* us a small example of the input file.

Comment: Oh, and in your real code you *do* check for errors? Like checking if the file was opened successfully?

Comment: If you initialise `x` to something,  that's the value you're going to see. My crystal ball thinks that you're running inside an IDE of some sort and need to read about the concept of "working" (or "current") directory.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to debug (if you are on a recent Windows) is is to [download](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#) and install the free version of Visual Studio and press F5.

The second easiest way is to insert debug output showing the state of variables etc.

The best way to *prevent* the need for debugging is to check the success of important steps in your program; `ifstream` has a conversion to bool indicating whether the stream is in good shape. It can be used like `if( !input_file ) { fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n"); }`.

One thing that caught my eye in your specific case is that you put the file name in single quotes. Did that compile? Try double quotes in any case and make sure to use double backslashes for Windows directory separation. An issue which comes up frequently is that it is not always clear which directory is the working directory of the program (which influences the meaning of relative paths); use absolute paths like `"c:\\myfile.txt"` to be unambiguous. If the file could not be opened the attempts to read from that stream will fail and `x` will keep its original (undefined, "random", because you don't initialize it) value.

Accessing an uninitialized variable is generally undefined behavior. That is, the program could legitimately crash or, as in this case, show a seemingly arbitrary value.